# Should I provide x or log(x) to predict() if my model is y ~ log(x)?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, predict

I have a fitted `lm` model

```
log_log_model = lm(log(price) ~ log(carat), data = diamonds)`
```

I want to predict `price` using this model, but I'm not sure if I should be entering `log(carat)` or `carat` value as predictor into the `predict()` function?

**Choice 1**

```
exp(predict(log_log_model, data.frame(carat = log(3)),
            interval = 'predict', level = 0.99))
```

**Choice 2**

```
exp(predict(log_log_model, data.frame(carat = 3),
    interval = 'predict', level = 0.99))
```

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Choice 2 is correct.**

To give you some extra bit of confidence, let's inspect what the design matrix looks like when we make prediction.

```
## for diamonds dataset
library(ggplo2)

## log-log linear model
fit <- lm(log(price) ~ log(carat), data = diamonds)

## for prediction
newdat <- data.frame(data.frame(carat = 3))

## evaluate the design matrix for prediction
Xp <- model.matrix(delete.response(terms(fit)), data = newdat)
#  (Intercept) log(carat)
#1           1   1.098612
```

See it? `carat = 3` is automatically evaluated to `log(carat) = log(3)`.